# Cannot set trigger within TabControl template in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers, tabcontrol, tabitem

I wrote a style for my **TabControl**. Within the TabControl I have a **TextBlock** and a **Button**. I wish to set trigger for TabItem.IsSelected such that the font colour of the text within TextBlock changed. My code below doesn't work:

```
  <Style x:Key="_tabItemButtonStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroTabItem}" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
      <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Name="_TabHeaderStackPanel" >
                            <TextBlock Text="{ Binding TabName }" Name="_TabHeaderText" Background="{ Binding TabBackColour }" FontSize="{ Binding TabFontSize }" >
                                <TextBlock.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected,
                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TabItem}}" 
                                            Value="True">
                                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="SteelBlue"/>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </TextBlock.Style>

                            </TextBlock>
       ...
```

The problem I suspect is with this code:

```
                                 <TextBlock.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected,
                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TabItem}}" 
                                            Value="True">
                                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="SteelBlue"/>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </TextBlock.Style>
                            </TextBlock>
```

**EDIT:**

I bind my tab items to a Collection of ViewModels. So my style binding looks as following:

```
 <TabControl x:Name="_MainTabControl"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"
                    SelectedIndex="0"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding OpenTabs}"
                    ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource _tabItemButtonStyle}" />
```

Comment: Just move the style with triggers outside of your `DataTemplate`, it should work then. P.S. place it in your `TabControl.Resources`. HTH

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what MetroTabItem is. But the other Code looks fine.
I tried it out with sample Code. And it does exactly what you describe you want to achieve.

Please check whether your Styles are correctly applied with Style={StaticResource YourStyleName} on the TabItem

Here my XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}" x:Key="TestStyle">
        <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Name="_TabHeaderStackPanel" >
                        <TextBlock Text="test" Name="_TabHeaderText" Background="{ Binding TabBackColour }" FontSize="{ Binding TabFontSize }" >
                            <TextBlock.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected,
                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TabItem}}" 
                                        Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="SteelBlue"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </TextBlock.Style>

                        </TextBlock>
                        <Button Content="Test"></Button>
                        </StackPanel></DataTemplate></Setter.Value>

                    </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem Style="{StaticResource TestStyle}">
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Style="{StaticResource TestStyle}">

        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: I have included a small edit on my post, please take a look. Maybe because of the way I bind the style I get this issue. Thanks

Comment: The way you set the style is okay too, works with my example fine. Can you maybe add the code for MetroTabItem or let me know where this Resource comes from.